# How to slow down this Node looping http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to call this API with the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module about 200-300 times with a Lambda function. I need to add second between each call so I don't get a 429 response. I've tried a few different ways to make this happen, but it seems to ignore the code to slow it down.

How do people normally slow down these requests in AWS lambda? It would be great if I could insert something like utilities.sleep(1000) in the loop to make it wait a second before continuing. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this issue, but all the examples I've seen seem to make it complex.

```
function findProjects(items){

    var toggleData = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){
        setTimeout( callToggle( items[i] ), 1000 );
    }

    function callToggle( data ){
        request({
            'url': 'https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects/' + data.toggle.data.id,
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            'auth': {
                'user': 'xxxxxxx',
                'pass': 'api_token'
        }}, function( error, response, body ){
            if( error ) {

                console.log( error );
                context.done( null, error );
            } else {

                console.log(response.statusCode, "toggle projects were listed");
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                toggleData.push(info);
            }
        });
    }

    findDocument( toggleData );   
}
```

Comment: Recursive function execution with `setTimeout()` between calls

Comment: i give you an example. At time `T0` you iterate `1000` times and start 1000 `setTimeout` with 1000ms of delay. I don't know how time pass between the first ant the 1000 call but very very little. Then you start 1000 times your method after exactly 1s. You should increment your time each time. ES: `setTimeout(function, 1000+i)`

Comment: Maybe this is useful http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachLimit

Comment: Don't do that: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Speedup-Loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    setTimeout(callToggl, 1000 + (( i * X ) % Y), items[i]);
}
```

Where `Y` is the max delay `(1000 + Y)` then you want (es 5 sec) and `X` is the timing for each call (es `X=10` : 1000,1010,1020,1030,...

if you want 1s each call:

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    setTimeout(callToggl(items[i]), 1000 + ( i * 1000 ));
}
```

*EDIT*

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    setTimeout(callToggl, 1000 + ( i * 1000 ), items[i]);
}
```

Comment: This solution will create longer and longer timeouts, but it does not account for the time each API call takes. If the API specifies 1000ms time between calls, we make our first call and it eventually returns, and 1000ms later we make another call, the variability in the time the calls take could mean we'd break the API's timing requirements and be blacklisted.

Comment: @broguinn Yes i know. But if you wait one second after the response (your answer) you wait to much (`TTL` and getting the data). Otherwise you can simply doing the next request recursively in the callback.

Comment: Yeah, thought so too. Ideally we have some sort of util that takes a promise-returning function and a timeout and returns a promise after both the function has completed **and** the timeout is done. Maybe like `Promise.all([Promise.wait(1000), Promise.resolve(makeRequest())])`

Comment: @gianlucatursi I added the code above to my for loop, but it still seems to call them all way faster than a second between the calls. I even changed the 1000 to 4000 `setTimeout(callToggl(items[i]), 1000 + ( i * 4000 ));` with the same result.

@broguinn you are correct in your comment, but for this API I don't need to worry about how often I call the API. It just can't be called too often. (Their docs say about 1 request per second is recommended.)

Comment: @BritGwaltney with that code the function will not execute each second? strange. can you put a `console.log(new Date())` as a first line of `callToggl`? you should see each second a new date

Comment: Here's what the logs output https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwoh4nckhhqu7n4/Screenshot%202016-08-31%2013.42.53.png?dl=0 

Do you think it could relate to this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184702/settimeout-not-delaying-a-function-call

Comment: @BritGwaltney i don't know but you can try with `setTimeout(callToggl,( i * 1000 ),items[i]);` or `setTimeout(function() { callToggl(items[i]); },2000);`. if it works I realized something new: D

Comment: You can't do that this way. setTimeout means that even will be fired in no less than `x` milliseconds. In other words, if you set 1000, 2000, 3000. If handling the first request takes 2 seconds and the 2 last request takes 10ms to be handled. The third request will be fired 10ms after the second request which will break the rule. The only way to assure that you don't break the rule is to chain calls.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, javascript code does not block on io (unless using specific sync api's which block your entire code which is a bad practice that should be avoided unless you have a really good reason to block the entire code(loading config files on startup... etc...))

so what you need to do, is simply wait for the response

it used to be a bit complicated in the past to orchestrate it all, 
but currently, using --harmony flag (to activate latest js features in node)  you can use the shiny new async functions syntax. (await/async)

the function you are running inside must be declared async, then after each iteration, you need to wait for the response of that http call using "await" keyword. 
this keyword makes the code seem as if its blocking and waiting for the resolved answer, although its not.

i used "fetch" instead of "request" because it plays nice with async functions (being promise based) but you can use any other method as long as you return a promise. (you can even promisify your existing callback based api with Promise object, but it will make everything look uglier, so please don't :) )

here is the modified code.
I'm not really sure if it works as is. But the idea is pretty clear i think.

On any case, its a great opportunity for you to learn how to work with async functions in case you didn't use them already, they really make life easier.

```
//making enture function async, so you can use 'await' inside it
async function findProjects(items){

    var toggleData = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){
        //setTimeout( callToggle( items[i] ), 1000 );
        //instead of using a timeout, you need to wait for response before continuing to next iteration
        await response = callToggle(items[i]);
        toggleData.push(JSON.parse(response.body));
    }

    async function callToggle( data ){
        /*request({
            'url': 'https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects/' + data.toggle.data.id,
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            'auth': {
                'user': 'xxxxxxx',
                'pass': 'api_token'
        }}, function( error, response, body ){
            if( error ) {

                console.log( error );
                context.done( null, error );
            } else {

                console.log(response.statusCode, "toggle projects were listed");
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                toggleData.push(info);
            }
        });*/
        // to make things simpler, use fetch instead of request which is promise based
        var myInit = {  'method': 'GET',
                        'headers': {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        },
                        'auth': {
                            'user': 'xxxxxxx',
                            'pass': 'api_token'
                        }
                    };
        return fetch("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects/",myInit);
    }

    findDocument( toggleData );   
}
```

Comment: Hey this is really cool. I had not seen this before. I did have to change where I put "await" due to an error. It would be: response = await callToggle(items[i]);
I was able to use this in my code by moving things out into secondary functions, especially the ajax() call within a loop, and putting async and await in the right place. 
I am not using Node.js but am using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the requests together:

```
function findProjects(items){

    var toggleData = [];

    // chain requests with delay
    items.reduce(function (requestChain, item) {
      return requestChain
        .then(callToggle.bind(null, item))
        .then(wait.bind(null, 1000));
    }, Promise.resolve());

    function wait (ms) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
      });
    }

    function callToggle(data) {
        request({
            'url': 'https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects/' + data.toggle.data.id,
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            'auth': {
                'user': 'xxxxxxx',
                'pass': 'api_token'
        }}, function( error, response, body ){
            if( error ) {

                console.log( error );
                context.done( null, error );
            } else {

                console.log(response.statusCode, "toggle projects were listed");
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                toggleData.push(info);
            }
        });
    }

    findDocument( toggleData );   
}
```

Comment: I had a similar question and I want you to know that this answer was perfection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While Node.js is single-threaded, setTimeout does not create a single stack of synchronous calls. When you use your `for` loop you immediately set each subsequent call to 1000ms ahead, so they all activate at roughly the same time. Instead, you likely want to use a third-party promise lib to wait.

You could do something as simple as:

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');
const $http = require('http-as-promised');
const _ = require('lodash');

const timeout = 1000;
const items = []; 
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' };
const auth = { 'user': 'xxxxxxx', 'pass': 'api_token' };

const makeRequest = (id) => {
  const url = 'https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects/' + id;
  return $http.get({ url, headers, auth }); 
};

const waitCall = (data) => {
    return Bluebird
    .resolve(makeRequest(data.toggl.data.id))
    .wait(timeout);
};

Bluebird.mapSeries(items, waitCall);
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html