# How can I correctly implement setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `setTimeout` to perform `document.write` after a certain delay after a form is submitted. For now, the delay is a static 3000ms. However, when I try to implement it, `document.write` happens instantly. How can I implement setTimeout correctly?

This is for a website. Form submission happens before this block of code runs, and variables are passed from what is submitted.

```
function findInterval(){
var delay = document.forms["options"]["delay"].value;
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.ceil(max);
var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
var total = parseInt(delay) + parseInt(result);
setTimeout(document.write(total), 3000);
}
```

My understanding is that my code should wait 3 seconds, then do `document.write(total)` but that's not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The first paramter of `setTimeout` is a callback function.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.write(total)}, 3000);
```

Comment: There is a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184702/settimeout-not-delaying-a-function-call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. Looking at the duplicate question helped too. However, my new line of code is:

`setTimeout(function(){document.write(total);}, 3000);`

and nothing happens. Do I still have something wrong?

Comment: You should check the `total` variable value.